# Effect of training data on complexity of kernel

Tags: machine-learning, svm, time-complexity

How does the amount of training data affect the complexity of a linear kernel in support vector machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the number of training inputs $n$ and their dimension $d$.

Linear SVMs will typically be solved in the primal, so that a model is represented by a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and an offset $b \in \mathbb R$. Prediction is done as
$$
\hat y = \mathrm{sign}(w^T x + b)
$$
which happens in $O(d)$ time, independent of $n$.

Training time depends on the algorithm used, but the typical linear SVM solvers (e.g. LIBLINEAR) are linear in $n$. For example, see

> Thorsten Joachims. *Training Linear SVMs in Linear Time.* KDD 2016. ([author's pdf](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_06a.pdf), [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1150402.1150429))

Kernel SVM solvers (e.g. LIBSVM) are somewhat harder to quantify but take time more like $n^3$.